# Are there any drawback of using output buffer on do_action function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function where I need to use apply_filter and couple of action in between. Are there any drawbacks of using this approach? Are there alternatives?

```
$form = array ('choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3') 
$content= "";
foreach ($form as $choice ) {

    ob_start();
    do_action( 'before_choice', $form_id, $choice );
    $content .= ob_get_clean(); 

    $content .='<div class="choice-container">'. $choice .'</div>';

    ob_start();
    do_action( 'after_choice', $form_id, $choice );
    $content .= ob_get_clean();                     

}
$content = apply_filters( 'change_choices_layout', $content, $form  );
echo $content;
```

Comment: I don't think there is a drawback but I will probably use the buffer on all the loop instead for each action.

Comment: I need to output the result of do_action in its exact position, not sure if this would work in my case.

Comment: you can assign the value for the content at the end like this https://eval.in/898384

Answer (score 0):

If it's static content my alternative would be to use transients which are much faster to render on screen.  The issue with ob_start() is that if you or someone else modified the action 'before_choice' and put another call to ob_start() within it then it makes it difficult to troubleshoot what's going on as the content would disappear.  I would also change your `do_action` to `apply_filters`, rewrite your 'before_choice' hook to be an `add_filter` instead of an `add_action` hook as filters will return a value by default so you don't need to use ob_start() anymore.

Comment: I tried apply_filter, but the issue with it is that if use like this `apply_filter( 'after_choice', $form_id, $choice, $somevalue );`  considering  `$somevalue` has the value 40. it will always return 40 in this position since we used echo $content at the end.

Comment: You haven't included any of your filter definitions so I can't comment on what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a better solution would be to use it like this:

```
$form = array ('choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3') 
$content= "";
foreach ($form as $choice ) {

    if ( has_filter( 'wwob_after_product_item_price') ){
        $content .= apply_filters( 'wwob_after_product_item_price', $form_id, $choice );    
    }           

    $content .='<div class="choice-container">'. $choice .'</div>';

    if ( has_filter( 'after_choice') ){
        $content .= apply_filters( 'after_choice', $form_id, $choice ); 
    }                 

}
$content = apply_filters( 'change_choices_layout', $content, $form  );
echo $content;
```